# Unable to put 3 buttons and 1 edit text inside a relative layout

Tags: android

I am unable to put these 3buttons and 1 Edit text inside the relative layout. 
Basically, I was list view on top and then a relative view under the list view. This relative view will consists of edit text in first row and 3 buttons in second row.

Everything is working fine but, when i put 1 edittext and 3 buttons in relative layout, i get error 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Can someone please help , really appreciate your time.
Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.com.date.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled">



    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/messageBox"
        android:id="@+id/chatroom"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/messageBox"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sendButton"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:hint="send message" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/galleryButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messageBox"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messageBox"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/galleryButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_width="75dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This code works perfectly fine for me. Circular dependencies come when reference of two views are set for eachother. Say button1 is to left of button2 and button2 is right of button1. This will cause circular dependency error.

Comment: This code is fine , but I want to put edit text and 3 button inside an extra relative layout

Comment: Outter Relative layout -- list view -- inner relative layout (edit text ,3 buttons) -- end of inner relative layout -- end of outer relative layout

Comment: what is your exact needed layout? can you post the picture or draw the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code hope this can help you..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chatroom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:hint="send message"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/galleryButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/galleryButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you are incredible, This code worked like a charm. I just changed button layout weights to .15 .15 .20 , first 2 buttons appear on the left side which is what i want , but for the last one i am trying to change gravity to right but its not wokring, how cn i move last button to extreme right ... thanks

Comment: welcome bro.. if this can help you then please ACCEPT and UPVOTE this..Thanks

Comment: welcome , sure will do that .. can you please move third button to extreme right when all layout weights are .10

Answer (score 0):

Try your same code with little modification. It works fine for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="app.com.date.MainActivity"
android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled">



<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/messageBox"
    android:id="@+id/chatroom"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/messageBox"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sendButton"
    android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:hint="send message" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/galleryButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/messageBox"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/messageBox"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/galleryButton" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code please try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/testbutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="edittext " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/LstPeriodOptions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnLL" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just posted and easiest layout.

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/activity_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">               

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/chatroom"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/messageBox"
                    android:divider="@null"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/messageBox"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:background="#eee"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/galleryButton"                
                    android:hint="send message" />               

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/galleryButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:text="gallery"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Camera"                
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sendButton"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/galleryButton"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/galleryButton"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/messageBox"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                    android:text="Send"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

UI should not unwanted deeper.try to finish as simple as best. then only UI will be faster.

so your layout will be like

[image]